# English dictionary for word games

Tags: word-games

There are lots of popular games now-days that enable a player to construct a word while opposing some limitations. If player constructs a valid word successfully, he gets a point. For this a big amount of English words is needed so that the game would be able to check if such a word exists in English. Where can I take such a bank of words? And how big the size will be? Would it we good for mobile games?

Comment: Please close my question as it is not related to games. Why gamedev people always tend to close questions? Good-old stackoverflow is better!

Comment: don't know if this is what you'r looking for but 5 seconds google search lead me to http://dictionary-api.org/sites/default/files/field/doc/android/Readme.html